# Find the dim of the solutions for $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be a matrix:
$$
        A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -5 & -6 & 1 \\
        2 & 1 & -7 & -7 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 & -8 & -11 & 5 \\
        1 & -1 & 1 & 4 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

1) Find a base for the row space and for the column space.

I did:

$$rref(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -3 & -5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So the base for the row space is: $\{[1,0,-2,-1,0],[0,1,-3,-5,0],[0,0,0,0,1]\}$, and the base for the column space is $\{        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        2 \\
        -1 \\
        \end{bmatrix},        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        5 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\}$

2) Find the dimension of the subspace of the solutions $Ax=0$ and the dimension of the subspace of the solutions for $A^ty=0$

Can someone please explain me how I would solve 2? I'm pretty sure I did well on 1) but I can't still see the sense behind this question (I guess I still haven't fully understood how to relate matrices to linear equations/systems)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in other word second question is about $\text{dim}(\text{ker}A)$. Next $A: \mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^4$. Now by [Rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) you have:

$$\text{dim}(\text{ker}A)+\text{dim}(\text{im}A)=\text{dim}\mathbb{R}^5=5$$

But you've calculated $\text{dim}(\text{im}A)$ yet. It's dim of column space, so $\text{dim}(\text{ker}A)=5-3=2$.

Answer (score 0):

let me write the columns $A$ as $a_1, a_2, \cdots.$  from your rref you can see that $2a_1 + 3a_2 + a_3 = 0, a_1 + 5a_2 + a_4 = 0$. this means 
$\pmatrix{2&3&1&0&0}^T, \pmatrix{1&5&0&1&0}^T$ are in the null space of $A.$ in fact the listed vecors is a basis for the null space of $A.$